# Why I don't always get the id of an element?

Tags: javascript

I dynamically create with PHP some buttons with an ID.
When I click on a button, I want to get the ID to use it with ajax.
But when I click on the button, sometimes it works, but other times not and i don't know why.
Even if I don't refresh the page and click some times on the button, there are different results.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
   var i;
   for(i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++){        
        deleteButtons[i].onclick = function(e){         
            var id = e.target.id;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200){                  
                    document.getElementById("deleteUser").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "lib/ajax/getusernamebyid.php?userid="+id, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        };  
        deleteButtons[i].disabled = false;
    }
});
```

**HTML Button**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><i class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML code?

Comment: Does the button have any HTML tags inside? If so, when clicking such element, `e.target` will be that element instead of the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is that some of your buttons have their children.

if so, sometimes when you're clicking on a button, actually you're clicking on one of its children. so `target` won't be your button and you won't able to get the button's id with `target.id`.

The solution is to use `e.currentTarget.id` to make sure that you are getting id of the button that you are clicking on so :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
   var i;
   for(i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++){        
        deleteButtons[i].onclick = function(e){         
            var id = e.target.id;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200){                  
                    document.getElementById("deleteUser").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "lib/ajax/getusernamebyid.php?userid="+id, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        };  
        deleteButtons[i].disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the Problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should debug this code with a console.log inside your script.

I suggest you use Jquery delegate

```
$("body").delegate(".delete","click",function(){ //your logic here  })
```

or in new version of Jquery

```
$(document).on(".delete","click",function(){ //your logic here})
```

or in pure javascript

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
for (var target=e.target; target && target!=this; target=target.parentNode) {
    if (target.className == "delete") {
        //your logic
        break;
    }
}}, false);
```